# Aptana / Eclipse Support for "js.erb", "css.erb" files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, jruby, aptana, erb

I'm working on jRuby on Rails app in Eclipse. I recently install Aptana to better support the rails files. This provides reasonable highlighting and support for most file types includes "html.erb" files but not for other *.erb files.

It's driving me insane their must be some editor that doesn't give me a damn syntax error when I use ruby tags in js.erb files. It seems like such a basic function.

Any advice is appreciated. I am open to pretty much anything I just want some way to write javascript in erb files without a million syntax errors after every ruby tag.

This example give me a syntax error in the editor despite working perfectly fine when I run the app:

```
    <%= render :partial => 'qunit/frame_wrapper_top' -%> 
    module("Carousel");
     asyncTest('Slider Right Button', 1, function() { 
        setTimeout(function() {
            var center_image = frame.find('.carouselContainer li img.current').attr('id');
            var e = $q.Event("click");
            $('.navButton_right').trigger( e );
            setTimeout(function(){
                start();
                var current_center = frame.find('.carouselContainer li img.current').attr('id');
                notEqual( current_center, center_image, "New item is in center");
            }, 1000);
        },1000); 
     });
```

Comment: which version of Aptana are you using? I have a stand-alone version of 3.1.x (the beta/nightly build) and I can create a test.js.erb file, paste your code and not get any error messages. I also have Studio 3.1.x installed as an Eclipse plugin. No problems on that version as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for an editor or IDE that can handle .js.erb. Aptana (3.0.9 or 3.2.0) only seems to recognise the ERB part, the JS does not get highlighted. Maybe Emacs+nXhtml will work.

**Update**: nXhtml does do the job for emacs. Load the file in your ~/.emacs as described in the README, then M-x eruby-javascript-mumamo-mode !